# Apache beam tranformations using python - Replace function - Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, regex, apache-beam

I'm trying to replace '-' with 0 in the below data

3019337728,APPLE IPHONE,2022-04,Preroll,DUBAI BRANCH,Saudi Arabia,Gender=Male,CPM,3,0,75000,-,-

The code I have used is :

```
import apache_beam as beam
p1=beam.Pipeline()
test1_beam=(
    p1
    |beam.io.ReadFromText('AUD-1.csv',skip_header_lines=1)
    |beam.Filter(lambda record:str(record[12][0])=="-")
    |beam.Regex.replace_all("-","%")
    |beam.io.WriteToText('replace-5.csv'))
      
p1.run()
```

But this doesnot work !!  The result file doesnt have anything in it.

When I tried to replace 3 with AAA in the index 0, it worked .

```
import apache_beam as beam
p1=beam.Pipeline()
test1_beam=(
    p1
    |beam.io.ReadFromText('AUD-1.csv',skip_header_lines=1)
    |beam.Filter(lambda record:str(record[0][0])=="3")
    |beam.Regex.replace_all("3","AAA")
    |beam.io.WriteToText('replace-4.csv'))
      
p1.run()
```

3019337728,APPLE IPHONE,2022-04,Preroll,DUBAI BRANCH,Saudi Arabia,Gender=Male,CPM,3,0,75000,-,-

AAA019AAAAAA7728,APPLE IPHONE,2022-04,Preroll,DUBAI BRANCH,Saudi Arabia,Gender=Male,CPM,AAA,0,75000,-,-

All the 3's were changed to AAA .

But why am I not able to replace the hyphens which are at positions 12 and 13 (index 11 and 12).I beleive my indexing is getting wrong.

Can any one help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You pipeline doesn't seem to be correct as ReadFromText only gives you a PCollection of str. You have to split/parse your input into structured records.

And beam.Regex.replace_all only takes in str as input not structured records.

So you can do

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
Record:
  # Define the schema of your record

def parse(record: str):
  split_record = record.split(',')
  split_record[11] = 0 if split_record[11] == '-' else split_record[11]
  split_record[12] = 0 if split_record[12] == '-' else split_record[12]
  return Record(*split_record)  # Make sure you convert each field to the right types

p1
|beam.io.ReadFromText('AUD-1.csv',skip_header_lines=1)
|beam.Map(lambda record: parse(x))
|beam.io.WriteToText('replace-4.csv'))
```